# share same remote docker in pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I am using a docker remote interpreter with pycharm-pro.
When running/debugging a program, I would like to run another python on the **same docker** instance.
What happens is that the pycharm opens a different container for each run.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Do you need to run another Python process in the same container with PyCharm or manually? The only thing which comes to my mind is to start a container manually with an SSH service running inside and setup remote-over-SSH-interpreter in PyCharm.

Comment: I thought of this too but then the all docker remote interpreter option is redundant. I have two processes (client and local server) that need to run on the same machine (docker). When I working on native linux I launch the server from pycharm (in debugging), then run the client from pycharm (in debugging) and now I can debug both. I want to do the same on docker.

Comment: Can the client and the server talk over the network? You can utilize docker-compose to run the processes in the separate containers.

Comment: No. They use named pipes

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution after a bunch of experiments, you need to use `docker-compose up` to start a service with you server and then `docker-compose exec` to run the client in the same container. So my setup:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:latest
RUN mkdir /opt/project
WORKDIR /opt/project
COPY server.py /opt/project
COPY client.py /opt/project
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  python:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project
```

1. Setup `docker-compose`-based interpreter in PyCharm
2. Run `server.py`, PyCharm will start `python` service with running server inside
3. Create a run configuration for `client.py` and specify `exec` as a command

[image]

4. Run this new client run configuration - PyCharm will execute `client.py` in the same container as a running server

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late response.
I tried and it is not working for debug: 
Error running 'client': Debug is not available for Docker Compose `exec` command